# Is it bad practice to directly generate XML for sending to a WCF web service?

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, wsdl, for-xml-path

Before I was given the wsdl for a web service, I had already generated the xml using SQL and FOR XML PATH.

Now I have the wsdl, should I go back and populate each object individually from SQL, should I deserialise my XML into the request object (if that is possible) or is there another choice? Any gotchas you can warn me about in advance?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CodeCaster. Can I expand the initial question a bit. The wsdl contains an inline xsd, but I can see that the restrictions in the xsd are not in the object model created from it. Is the inline xsd used at any point at runtime or are these validations actually not being used? If they are being used, are they used when the objects are created or when the objects are serialised down to xml?

Comment: <xsd:simpleType name="forenameType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:maxLength value="18" />
          <xsd:minLength value="2" />
          <xsd:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z'-]*" />
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell if you are posting a complicated xml structure from a SQL database to a WCF web service then there is no harm in creating the whole xml document using FOR XML PATH - in fact I would say it was better and simpler. You can then manually validate it against the xsd (which WILL validate against xsd:restrictions, minOccurs, maxOcurs etc) and then deserialise it into the complex object hierarchy created by the WSDL. Note that the WSDL does not do any validations (xsd:restrictions, minOccurs, maxOccurs are not validated on the client side) - it just creates the object hierarchy.

This assumes you are comfortable with SQL and XML PATH of course! Otherwise you can build the object hierarchy up in code, but you won't have any validation until you call the real web service.

The xsd validation is a belt and braces backup to avoid sending invalid data to the web service. Clearly, in the real world, whatever data you are sending should be validated properly with user friendly error messages.

Here's some sample code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Schema
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports ClassLibrary1.ServiceReferences.ClientX
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class ClientXWebServices

Private _isValid As Boolean?
Private _xmlErrorList As New List(Of String)
Private _xmlWarningList As New List(Of String)

Sub New()

End Sub

Function Send(id As Guid) As StoreData.storeDataResponse
    Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString())
        cnn.Open()
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("employer.clientx_xml_setup_select", cnn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)

        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader
            If (reader.Read()) Then
                xdoc.Load(reader)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using

    'Validate (belt and braces)
    Dim myschema As XmlSchema
    Using reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader("storeData.xsd")
        myschema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, Nothing)
    End Using
    xdoc.Schemas.Add(myschema)
    xdoc.Validate(AddressOf DocumentValidationCallback)
    If Not _isValid.HasValue Then
        _isValid = True
    End If
    If _isValid = False Then
        MsgBox(String.Join(vbCrLf, _xmlErrorList.Union(_xmlWarningList).ToArray))
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim xmlSer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(StoreData.storeDataRequest))
    Dim ssdr As StoreData.storeDataRequest = xmlSer.Deserialize(New StringReader(xdoc.OuterXml))
    Dim client As New StoreData.StoreDataClient
    Dim response As StoreData.storeDataResponse
    Try
        response = client.ServiceReferences_CLIENTX_StoreData_StoreData_storeData(ssdr)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New IOException("ClientX Web Service 'StoreData' could not be contacted.", ex)
    End Try

    Return response
End Function

Sub DocumentValidationCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ValidationEventArgs)
    If args.Severity = XmlSeverityType.Warning Then
        _xmlErrorList.Add(args.Message)
    ElseIf args.Severity = XmlSeverityType.Error Then
        _xmlWarningList.Add(args.Message)
    End If
    _isValid = False
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

If it works, it works.

Generating client code and classes from WSDL has multiple benefits over handcrafting XML: they are easily updated and not prone to copy-paste errors like the latter option.